# Stream a PDF to a web page failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a URL to a PDF and I want to serve up the PDF to my page viewer.

I can successfully (I think) retrieve the PDF file.  Then when I do the Response.BinaryWrite() I get a "The file is damaged and could not be repaired" error from the adobe reader.

Here's the code I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            byte[] output = DoWork("Http://localhost/test.pdf");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.PDF");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", output.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(output);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    public byte[] DoWork(string requestUrl)
    {
        byte[] responseData;
        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        StreamReader strmReader = null;

        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

            using (resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[resp.ContentLength];
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                responseData = buffer;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (req != null)
            {
                req = null;
            }

            if (resp != null)
            {
                resp.Close();
                resp = null;
            }
        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

Comment: are you able to download it using this, I mean letting a browser (or wget) do the work?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I need to use ReadBytes()  For some reason, when reading a PDF from a URL, You don't get all of the bytes that you requested.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            byte[] output = DoWork("Http://localhost/test.pdf");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", output.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(output);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    public byte[] DoWork(string requestUrl)
    {
        byte[] responseData;
        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        StreamReader strmReader = null;

        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

            using (resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[resp.ContentLength];
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    buffer = reader.ReadBytes(buffer.Length);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                responseData = buffer;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (req != null)
            {
                req = null;
            }

            if (resp != null)
            {
                resp.Close();
                resp = null;
            }
        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the resulting file to your disk. Then open the file with a text editor. Maybe there are some errors in your script/source file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use FileStream the read the file

```
 string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath 
                  + "\\document\\Test.pdf";
 FileStream fStream = new FileStream
            (strPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(fStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the response after the binary write...

```
Response.BinaryWrite(output);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Alternatively, instead of inline, try to output the PDF as an attachment:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MyPDF.PDF");
```

Comment: Flush is not a method on BinaryReader

Comment: Replaced it with Close according to MSDN: Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close.

Comment: flushing a reader?? what somehow doesn't make much sense... :) You read until it's empty, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

When I did this in Perl the other day (as a quick *hack* for our intranet), the crux of the script was:

```
binmode(STDOUT);
print "Content-type: application/pdf\n\n";
binmode(FILE);
print <FILE>;
close(FILE);
```

The key points being to make sure that the input *and* output streams are in binary mode, i.e. as you've found, the PDF needs to be interpreted as binary data throughout the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simplify your code quite a bit by using the WebClient class

[Here's the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) Its not as cumbersome as the lower level HttpWebRequest class.