# Writing binary to android browser from asp.net

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I'm trying to stream PDF files through the website I am working on. The process I have listed below works fine on iPhones and desktop browsers, but for some reason it won't work on Android devices. It starts the download but then says "Download in progress" indefinitely. If I place the PDF file in the website's file path and type the URL of the PDF file, the download works perfectly. In our case, however, we can't afford to have the PDF files available through a URL.  I've looked up other answers online and none of them fixed my problem. Any ideas?

This is the code I have so far:

```
Protected Sub SendFile()
    Dim output As Byte() = GetByteArray()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName.PDF")
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", output.Length.ToString())
    Response.BinaryWrite(output)
End Sub

Public Function GetByteArray() As Byte()
    Dim responseData As Byte()
    Dim req As FileWebRequest = Nothing
    Dim resp As FileWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As BinaryReader = Nothing
    Try
        req = FileWebRequest.Create(fileName)
        resp = req.GetResponse
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(resp.ContentLength - 1) {}
        reader = New BinaryReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
        buffer = reader.ReadBytes(buffer.Length)
        responseData = buffer
    Finally
        If req IsNot Nothing Then
            req = Nothing
        End If
        If resp IsNot Nothing Then
            resp.Close()
            resp = Nothing
        End If
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then
            reader.Close()
            reader = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    Return responseData
End Function
```

Comment: Looks very similar to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483865/stream-a-pdf-to-a-web-page-failing?rq=1

Comment: Can you check after adding Response.Flush() at the end of the sendfile function?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! @user2930100 I just tried the Response.Flush method but it still isn't working :/